# Cannot start service app: oci runtime error - executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I get the following error when I run docker-compose:

```
Cannot start service app: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"script.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH"
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  app:
    build: app
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\svirl\Documents\workspace\bgs-web:/var/www/html/:rw
```

and in `app` folder I have

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

ADD script.sh /var/www/html
RUN chmod +x /var/www/html/script.sh
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
ENTRYPOINT ["script.sh"]
```

and in same folder script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
composer install
```

Is there something I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exec syntax of the entrypoint (with the json) needs the full path to the binary, or /var/www/html would need to be added to the path. Update your Dockerfile to the following:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

ADD script.sh /var/www/html
RUN chmod +x /var/www/html/script.sh
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/html/script.sh"]
```

Comment: I am sorry but now I get `ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/var/www/html/script.sh\": stat /var/www/html/script.sh: no such file or directory"` but the file is there is I `RUN ls -la` on docker-compose.

Comment: Include your docker-compose.yml. Most likely you are trying to mount a volume somewhere in the /var/www/html path.

Comment: You'll need to include your script.sh on your host and set the execute bits in a way that map into the container. It may be easier to move the script.sh somewhere else inside your image that doesn't get replaced by your volume mount.

Comment: I choose the second way, the error is gone at build but when I start the container I get: `standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"` . `FROM php:5.6-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

ADD script.sh /var/www
RUN chmod +x /var/www/script.sh
RUN ls -la /var/www
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/script.sh"]`

Comment: Make sure you have /bin/bash inside your container, you may need /bin/sh instead. Also make sure you don't have windows linefeeds in your script, running dos2unix on the script can fix that.

Comment: It was Windows Endings. Thank you.